# Mail-merge like operation with sed (or similar)

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, sed

I would like to perform the following operation:

Given a file like this:

```
update FOO set STATUS="X" where ID=<REPLACE>;
insert into BAR (Z,W) values(<REPLACE>, 42);
```

And a file like this:

```
25478975
65897895
```

Give me a file with each line in the second file inserted in the `<REPLACE>` positions in the first, like this:

```
update FOO set STATUS="X" where ID=25478975;
insert into BAR (Z,W) values(25478975, 42);
update FOO set STATUS="X" where ID=65897895;
insert into BAR (Z,W) values(65897895, 42);
```

It probably won't take me too long to write a simple Python program to do this, but I strongly suspect I could do it by combining a few GNU/Linux commandline-tools in the right way. Can anyone show me how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while read line
do
  sed 's#<REPLACE>#'"$line"'#g' infile.tmpl
done < numbers.dat
```

Comment: Great! But how would I do this if I had more variables to change?